# Translation of "desafuero" to English

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

[WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=desafuero) says that the Spanish word *desafuero* can be used to refer to the "withdrawal of parliamentary/ministerial privileges." I recently saw this word used in this sense in a newspaper article. Is there a single word or phrase in English that has this technical meaning? Or would it be translated as the whole definition: "withdrawal of parliamentary/ministerial privileges"?

[The article's](http://www.laprensa.com.ni/2012/02/02/poderes/89329) headline was: "Insisten en desafuero a Montealegre."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized there's an [English Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desafuero) on this exact concept. It says:

> The Spanish-language term ***desafuero*** refers to the process through which a government official's official immunity to criminal prosecution is removed.
>
> Strictly speaking the term is incorrect, as *fuero* (from Latin "forum") refers to the freedom of speech protection enjoyed by members of Congress, but since this protection is frequently confused with the immunity against criminal prosecution of top executive branch officials, the term is commonly used by the public in this latter sense.

[Another Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desafuero_of_AMLO) talks about a famous *desafuero* case in Mexico. The [Spanish Wikipedia article](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desafuero) explains:

> El **desafuero** es el acto jurídico mediante el cual a una persona aforada se le retiran sus privilegios.

So it sounds like *desafuero* is a technical legal/government term used in certain governments of Spanish-speaking countries, and its proper English translation is... "desafuero."

Comment: Not only. Desafuero also has a common meaning, which is what I explain in my answer. Please check the DRAE.

Comment: @CesarGon: Ah ok. In this question though I was thinking specifically about its legal definition.

Answer (score 1):

The Spanish "fuero" can be translated as "charter", as in a grant of authority or rights. "Aforar", therefore, means to grant a charter to someone or something. "Desaforar" means to withdraw a charter from someone or something. And "desafuero" is the withdrawal of a charter. It could be roughly translated as "de-charting". I know, it's not pretty, but I can't think of anything better.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few words in English that have the same meaning but nothing exact. If you brake the word down "des" prefix for undoing or disjointed and "afuera" is outside.

Getting grounded by your parents is a "disafuero" it is a taking of some basic fredom(s) or right.

Being on parole can be construed as a "disafuero"

Comment: "afuera" doesn't have anything to do with "desafuero". "Desafuero" comes from "fuero" which is a type of privilege.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the cited article says:

> El economista Néstor Avendaño insistió ante la primera secretaría de la Asamblea Nacional en su **solicitud de desafuero** para el diputado Eduardo Montealegre, a quien acusa de injurias y calumnias.

Let's notice that the noun being affected is an individual person.  In that case, I would suggest

**impeach** or **unseat**

> impeach: **1b** To bring formal charges against (a public official) for wrongdoing while in office. ([American Heritage](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/impeach))
>
> unseat: **2** To dislodge from a location or position, especially to remove from office. ([American Heritage](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/unseat))

A helpful resource for you in this kind of challenge is [linguee.com](http://linguee.com), which sometimes includes side-by-side Spanish and English taken from European Union documents.

*Next time, the better place to ask about translating **from Spanish to English** would be [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com), where this type of question is on topic.  (Strictly speaking, here it is not.)*